# An argument for the binomial instead of exponential distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm struggling with a concept related to the following problem:

In a set of $n$ items we are looking for a single item which only occurs once in the set. The goal is to determine the means and distributions of looking for the item:

1. Linearly. Start at the front of the set and work towards the end until the item is found.
2. Randomly. Pick up an item, examine it, if it is not the item, put it back into the set and keep checking.

My reasoning for the linear search is that it follows the geometric distribution and therefore has a mean of $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{n}} = n$.

For the random search I have a bit of an issue. Because of the fact that we are replacing the objects I immediately think of the binomial distribution. We could have any number of bernoulli experiments $m$ between 1 and $\infty$, which makes me shy away a bit from the binomial. But this would give me a mean of $\frac{m}{n}$. I'm fairly certain the answer that I should be giving is the exponential distribution, but this makes less sense to me but would make sense given the open interval nature of the distribution.

Can anyone help me make a bit of sense with this one?

Comment: Hint: What is the expected number of examinations for the "random" method?

Comment: @Math1000 It could be an infinite amount, correct? I mean we could stand in the same spot and check the same item for the rest of our lives. Not that it would make sense to do so, but its a possibility.

Comment: It is not possible for it to be an infinite amount, because even if you checked the same item for the rest of your life, that is still a finite number of examinations. It is possible for the number of examinations to be very large, though, and on average it would be $n!$. Look up "bogosort" for an example of such an algorithm.